# Почему изменение const в цикле не вызывает ошибок и работает корректно?

Tags: javascript, константа

На просторах Интернета встретил несколько функций наподобие этого кода:

```
const popupLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-link");
if (popupLinks.length > 0){
    for (let i =0; i< popupLinks.length; ++i){
        const popupLink = popupLinks[i];
        popupLink.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        // делаем что-то при клике...
    });
    }
}
```

Интересует почему такой код не вызывает ошибок и даже предупреждений, ведь в строке:

```
const popupLink = popupLinks[i];
```

мы объявляем КОНСТАНТУ, константа меняться не может, а на второй и последующих итерациях цикла мы меняем ее. Как это работает? Мы же еще не вышли из цикла, соответственно идентификатор popupLink все еще занят значением, которое нельзя менять...  и создавать новую по идее нельзя. Пока старая константа еще существует, вторую с тем же именем запрещено создавать. Тем не менее, такие функции спокойно работают. Почему?

Comment: вы не изменяете ее а создаёте новую

Comment: @AzizUmarov так и создавать новую по идее нельзя. Старая еще существует, а вторую с тем именем запрещено создавать, разве нет?

Comment: а если посмотреть на это так for (let i =0; i< popupLinks.length; ++i){ somefunc();}
function somefunc(){
        const popupLink = popupLinks[i];
        popupLink.addEventListner("click", function(e){
        // делаем что-то при клике...
    });}

Comment: @AzizUmarov Сложно! )) то есть это как бы локальная константа, которая каждый раз создается в новом экземпляре somefunc()?

Comment: Да точно как бы в блоке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если посмотреть на это таким образом

```
const popupLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-link");
if (popupLinks.length > 0){
    for (let i =0; i< popupLinks.length; ++i){
        somefunction(i);
    });
    }
}

function somefunction(var i) {
        const popupLink = popupLinks[i];
        popupLink.addEventListner("click", function(e){
        // делаем что-то при клике...
}
```

то думаю можно некоторые вопросы будут ясны с такой точки зрения

Попробую подобрать цитат [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) и [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let)

> Значение констант не может быть изменено новым присваиванием, а также не может быть переопределено. Константы (const) подчиняются
> области видимости уровня блока так же, как переменные, объявленные с
> использованием ключевого слова let.
>
> Областью видимости переменных, объявленных ключевым словом let,
> является блок, в котором они объявлены, и все его подблоки.

отсюда блок цикла это {} и всё что там объявлено

Answer (score 5):

модификатор `const` гарантирует только то, что переменной можно будет присвоить значение только один раз.

В приведенном коде, значение присваивается один раз

```
const popupLink = popupLinks[i];
```

следовательно все, в соответствии с требованиями.

На каждой итерации цикла создается своя собственная константа доступная только внутри текущей итерации.

Comment: Самое нужное - в одной последней строчке :) Можно вопрос вдогонку? Конкретно в коде из вопроса, зачем/почему используется именно `const`?

Comment: @UModeL Именно для того, чтобы зафиксировать факт, что в этом блоке кода значение этой переменной не будет меняться.

Comment: @UModeL, ну так очевидно потому что внутри итерации эта переменная не должна меняться. По сути это что-то вроде своего `for..of` где текущий элемент сохраняется в переменную для работы, а не идет работа с индексом

Comment: @UModeL где-то очень давно читал статью про использование `const`, `let`, `var`, суть была примерно такая: если переменная не должна изменятся в коде, то её необходимо обозначать константой, если переменная будет изменяться, то `let`. Визуально при указании типа переменной можно понять, будет ли эта переменная изменятся или нет. Если в коде присутствует `let variable` то можно уже понять что это переменная будет изменяться в коде ниже и её можно найти, нежели перебирать все обозначенные переменные.

Comment: Всем спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 3):

Когда вы объявляете константу в цикле, то при следующей итерации она создастся по новой. Поэтому ваша запись не вызывает никаких ошибок и все отлично работает.

Если вы перенесёте переменную `popupLink` на один уровень выше, то вы получите соответствующую ошибку, её решением будет просто изменить `const` на `let`

> Блоки кода задают область видимости констант, а константы,
> определенные на вложенных блоках кода, скрывают внешние константы с
> тем же именем

[Источник](https://metanit.com/web/javascript/3.2.php)

---

В вашем коде была ошибка в названии метода: `addEventListner`, вместо него следовало бы написать `addEventListener`

```js
const popupLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-link");

if (popupLinks.length > 0){
    for (let i =0; i< popupLinks.length; ++i){
        const popupLink = popupLinks[i];
        popupLink.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            // делаем что-то при клике...
            console.log('click');
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-link">Popup Link</div>
```

---

> На каждой итерации переменной присваивается значение другого свойства.
> переменная может быть объявлена ​​с помощью `const`, `let` или `var`.

[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```js
const popupLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".popup-link");

for (const popupLink of popupLinks) {
    popupLink.addEventListener("click", () => console.log('click'));
}
```

```html
<div class="popup-link">Popup Link</div>
<div class="popup-link">Popup Link</div>
```